# Absolute Layout

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-absolutelayout

Por error borre la librería de Absolute Layout, La volví a descargar pero cuando la intento seleccionar desde propiedades no me aparece.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya está en el classpath?

Comment: nose, como veo eso?

Comment: He visto algunas respuestas parecidas aqui en stackoverflow, te sugiero hagas la busqueda mas a profundidad.